# Firebase Realtime Database Listeners Pricing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had a question about the pricing of Firebase Realtime Database Listeners. I am planning on creating a chatroom using RTDB and I am curious about the pricing model.

When creating a listener on the messages group and a new item is added, does RTDB return ALL the messages or just the changes to the listener. And will I be charged for downloading all the data again or just charged for downloading the modified data by the listener.

The platform is web. There will potentially be millions of messages and I want to make sure that I can regulate the amount of messages being downloaded by each user.

The structure looks like this: [image: RTDB Screenshot]

Comment: A lot here depends on how you implement the listeners, your data model, and what platform your clients run on. Without knowing more details, it'll hard to say how your pricing will be pan out.

Comment: I'd also recommend thinking about what data the user actually needs. While there may be millions of messages, will a user actually read all of them? I typically recommend thinking of screenfulls of data; so starting with 10-20 messages and then loading the rest as needed.

Comment: Thx for the advice. I’ve uploaded a picture of my database format. That answers my second question actually. As for the first, imagine i set a listener on the “messages” group and a new item is added, do I get charged for the whole messages group or only the uploaded data by the listener?

Comment: What platform do your clients run on? Also: use all the answers to clarify your original question please, as it's too broad in its current form - and folks shouldn't have to read a comment trail to get clarity.

Comment: I've updated the original question now. It will be on web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the web the Firebase client reads all the nodes that match your condition.

So if you attach a listener to `/messages`, it will read all messages.

If you limit the results through a query (say, the 20 most recent messages) it will read only the nodes matching those criteria from the server.

Through cursor operations (like `startAt`/`startAfter`) you can implement load-on-demand, download only the data that the user is likely to see, and limit how much data you read, and thus pay for.

Comment: Thanks for this. What would happen if the data is updated after the listener is created. Charged for all messages or just the changes?

Comment: I just quickly tested this in a jsbin (https://jsbin.com/tixunah/edit?js,console). When I make a change to one of the child values, it only receives *that* child value. Note that you can only see this in the Network tab of the browser's developer console (check for Web Socket traffic), as the SDK merges the update with the existing data it has, and sends a full snapshot of the data to our code.

Comment: Ah interesting. Good that it reduces costs. Definitely will use this. Thanks Frank!